# Headless VNC on Ubuntu 20.04 Shows Black Screen on Login

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I've been running the built-in Vino VNC in Ubuntu 20.04 on a headless server for a while now and it works fine. The box does not have a monitor plugged in (and never has). Now, when I VNC into it I just get a black screen. If I close the VNC client and try to reconnect, I can't reconnect - it just times out/hangs.

I think this started when I unplugged the keyboard and mouse to use somewhere else and rebooted the server, but I'm not sure. Can anyone suggest what might be going on? I just want to be able to remote control using the console like I used to - not having to create new VNC sessions or anything.

I've tried killing the vino-server process and restarting it, but it doesn't help. I've also tried uncommenting the first two lines in the stock xstartup file but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

```
david@dalton:~$ more .vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```